# count a character in a string (C) - question

Tags: c, string, function

I have to write a program in C which finds the number of apparitions of a character which I choose.
This is my code:
Why if I remove de bold line the program does not work anymore ? I mean I don't understand what that line is doing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int number(char c)
{
    int i,nr=0;
    char s[50];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(s,49,stdin);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);++i)
        {
            if(s[i]==c)
            {
                nr++;
            }
        }
    return nr;
}

int main()
{
    int nra;
    char b;
    printf("Enter a character you want to count: ");
    b=getc(stdin);
    **getc(stdin);**
    printf("Call the function\n");
    nra=number(b);
    printf("The number of apparitions of chracter %c is  %d",b,nra);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: pressing `a` and enter results in 2 characters being input, `a` followed by `\n`.

Comment: OT: the function: `getc()` returns a `int`, not a `char`.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.   As it is, a `char` (usually) will not recognize a EOF.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fgets(s,49,stdin);`   The function: `fgets()` properly handles the full length of the input buffer, so no need to shorted the length by 1

Answer (score 1):

Why if I remove de bold line the program does not work anymore ? 
With the line being

```
getc(stdin);
```

When you input the char (read into `b`), you are leaving a newline character in the input stream. And `fgets()` function reads that newline and stops reading further input. That's why the extra call to `getc()` makes it work as it consumes the newline character - so `fgets()` waits for your intended input.

The standard input functions from stdio (`scanf`, `fgets`, `getc` and so on) are quirky and often lead to subtle errors. It's generally preferred to read input line-by-line and then parse to minimise unexpected errors.